# How to write an RSpec test for Ryan Bates' helper from screencast #228?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I followed along with [Ryan Bates' tutorial on sortable table columns](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns).

I attempted to write a spec for the `ApplicationHelper`, but the `#link_to` method fails.

Here is my spec:

```rb
require "spec_helper"

describe ApplicationHelper, type: :helper do
  it "generates sortable links" do
    helper.sortable("books") #just testing out, w/o any assertions... this fails
  end
end
```

Here is the output from running the spec:

```rb
1) ApplicationHelper generates sortable links
 Failure/Error: helper.sortable("books") #just testing out, w/o any assertions... this fails
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:sort=>"books", :direction=>"asc"}
 # ./app/helpers/application_helper.rb:5:in `sortable'
```

app/helpers/application_helper.rb(sortable method)

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    direction = (column == params[:sort] && params[:direction] == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, :sort => column, :direction => direction
  end
end
```

Comment: You have a link_to in your helper, and it points to a route that doesn't exist.

Comment: Has link_to's definition changed since that screencast was done in 2010?  That would be an older version of rails.

Comment: Thanks, but the code does actually work. I copied the code exactly as is from the screencast, and am using it w/o any problems.  The problem is writing a spec for it.

Comment: @ZPH - I am using Rails 4 with Ruby 1.9.3 and it works fine. I looked up the documentation and this appears to be valid syntax.

Comment: @KenrickChien Agreed, I fired up a Rails 4.1.0-rc1 application and your syntax is correct.  It looks like it requires the link to be generated for a valid controller... Trying to find an answer.

Comment: Well, no luck so far.  Found that it's raising the error from actionpack-4.1.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:39.  Keep me posted on twitter @_ZPH if you find a solution :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the error is happening because in your test, Rails doesn't know what's the controller/action for the url, in the way that you are generating the url, it will append {:sort => column, :direction => direction} to the current request params, but because there are not params, it will fail, so a simple way to fix it is:

```
describe ApplicationHelper, type: :helper do
   it "generates sortable links" do
       helper.stub(:params).and_return({controller: 'users', action: 'index'})
       helper.sortable("books") #just testing out, w/o any assertions... this fails
   end
end
```

and update your helper like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    direction = (column == params[:sort] && params[:direction] == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the easiest way is to pass the `request_params` into the `helper` rather than trying to stub out your params exactly like they are when running as a full stack.

```rb
def sortable(column, request_params, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  direction = (column == params[:sort] && params[:direction] == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
  link_to title, request_params
end
```