# Testing link_to without path in helper using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, stubbing

Using the tip [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to#32-Link-to-same-URL-with-different-format) I have built a method in a helper module like so:

```
describe ExampleHelper do
  def build_link
    link_to "RSS feed", params.merge(:format => :rss), :class => "feed_link"
  end
end
```

However, when I test this method I get the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: subject { helper.build_link }
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"index", :foo=>"bah", :foobah=>["1", "2", "3"], :results_per_page=>"25"}
 # /Users/tombrammar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@example/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:46:in `generate'
 # /Users/tombrammar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@example/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:721:in `generate'
 # /Users/tombrammar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@example/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:752:in `generate'
 # /Users/tombrammar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@example/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:799:in `url_for'
 # /Users/tombrammar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@example/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:156:in `url_for'
 # /Users/tombrammar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@example/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb:94:in `url_for'
 # /Users/tombrammar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@example/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:181:in `link_to'
```

It seems that because I'm testing within the helper it can't determine what controller to use and therefore how to build the url.

Can anyone help me understand how to fix this? I.e. perhaps I can stub the controller the helper rspec?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant route? (both in your routes file and via rake routes)

Comment: @TarynEast As I stated above, you can call `link_to` without passing in a path. It then tries to deduce your current path itself. It works fine in practice, but when testing via rspec (and therefore without a current controller) it throws this error.

Comment: As I stated above... (BTW that's an awful phrase probably you shouldn't use it) - can you please show us the route of the original page... because that will help us determine what params it expect and what is causing it to break :) and yes, without a current controller - it likely will simply not work - why is there no current controller in your spec?.

Comment: @TarynEast - haha..thank you. It wasn't meant to come out like that, but now you've pointed it out I can see what you mean. It's in a helper so it's used in many pages (controller actions) across the site. You ask `why is there no current controller in your spec?` how do you define a current controller in a helper spec?

Comment: oh in a helper spec - yeah I think I missed that part - I was thinking of this being tested in a controller spec for some reason :) Sorry - my brain-fart, pls ignore. There might be a way of designating a controller for the sake of the spec, but yeah I don't know it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a dirty trick if you are using params like above.

```
allow(helper).to receive(:params).and_return(_recall: { controller: 'homes' })
```

Also here is another way to do it that is a quick way to get the job done.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22265920/1431800